# Does Grails Project Structure change with Gradle?

Tags: grails, gradle

I am new to grails and have created my first project using grails-init. I now have a grails project that uses gradle as it's build tool. However, as I go through online tutorials I find that I am missing a lot of the files that are commonly cited. Files such as config.groovy and datasource.groovy.

I've tried re-creating the project, but I get the same structure and files. Can I just add these files manually? I have tried doing so, but they don't seem to be getting picked up when I run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Config.groovy` and `DataSource.groovy` are both applicable to Grails 2 applications but not Grails 3 applications.  In Grails 3 the default place for the information that used to go in those files is `application.yml`.

Comment: Those files exist in `grails-app/conf/`.

Answer (score 1):

Grails 3.1 have new features and structure changes. Now grails uses spring boot and Spring 4.2 and as mentioned, `Config.groovy` and `Datasource.groovy` can be configured using `application.yml`. You can found more information here [Grails documentation](https://grails.org/single-page-documentation.html)

Comment: "Grails 3.1 have new features and structure changes. " That isn't new to Grails 3.1.  We made those changes in 3.0.